# Rename the image while uploading?

Tags: php

this is an example I picked from W3School. Im just trying to modify this to suit my requirement.

What I need is when an image is uploaded, the image to be renamed in a sequence to so duplication is avoided. With this code if two users has two different images but if by chance if the name of the two different images are the same, one user will get a prompt saying 'already exists' preventing uploading.

I've tried replacing

`echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";`

with

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];`

but doesn't seems to be giving me a solution.

Can some one suggest me a way out to rename the images uploading in a sequence? Thanks.

**The code:**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to generate a unique ID for each uploaded file?

Comment: What you're doing is terrifying.  You're letting a user dictate what files you have on disk.  This is a huge security risk.  What if someone uploads `somethingevil.php`?

Comment: @Brad This won't let it `$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");` "unless" you name a `.php` file to one of the extensions allowed.

Comment: @Fred, If you think that buys you any security, you're crazy.  You can still upload whatever you want.  This script doesn't even verify that the path is within `upload/`!  What if I put something in `../../../`, etc.

Comment: @Larry.Z I think I'm trying to do that. So a unique ID would eliminate duplication? Can u suggest?

Comment: @Brad I never said it would "buy any security", you said that. And the "crazy" part, yeah.. you got that right.

Comment: @Brad Let's just stick to "the question" at hand, shall we?

Comment: @Fred, It is **critical** to point out issues in scripts like these.  People come to StackOverflow and copy/paste code all the time, without a clue of what the implications are.

Comment: @Brad You have a point there.

Comment: I suggest an answer to generate unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

try this

while moving uploaded file change file name `$yourFileNAME` to some unique value sucha as username or user id, so that no two files have same name.

```
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "upload/".$yourFileNAME."".$_FILES["file"]["type"] );
```

Comment: How do u suggest that I define '$yourFileNAME' ?

Comment: if the user have email id e.g sample123@gmail.como then you can take sample123 and save as image file name i.e $yourFileNAME="sample123"

Answer (score 0):

just change this line :
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $your_file_name)
and for your image name, you can use md5 of the file and timestamps to create an unique sequence

Answer (score 0):

Using the `uniqid()` PHP function will probably be your best method.

Note that,  if you generate identifiers simultaneously on several hosts that might happen to generate the identifier at the same microsecond

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

You can also generate uniqueid by mysql table.

```
create table ids(id int auto_increment primary key);
```

When users uploading their pics, write sql like this

```
insert into ids () values();
select last_insert_id();
```

Hope this will help you.